# how to strip string from url using rewrite rule

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, drupal-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

sometimes my drupal site add extra string to image url which causes the image to be broken.
the url is

```
http://mysite.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/list_image_page/%252Fsites/default/files/img.jpg
```

what is the needed rewrite rule to strip the bolded (%252F) part in the above link
ie. to be:

```
http://mysite.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/list_image_page/sites/default/files/img.jpg
```

I have tried this, but didn't work

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\%252Fsites(.*)$
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI}  %1sites%2
```

Comment: You should fix the broken Drupal code.

Comment: i wish that!!! i have tried it for 2 days!! but this is a bug in image cache module as appears in http://drupal.org/node/1212418

Answer (score 2):

You should try this rewrite rule to replace/strip.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)[%252F](.*)$ $1$2 [N]
```

Comment: it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a bug in Drupal? The last comment of the bug report you linked to says this:

> If you are using custom code, please remove the leading / in your image path.

Comment: this is if you are using custom code... but in my case i am using VIEWS module which is for drupal itself

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)%2Fsites(.*)$ $1sites$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```